# Java Swing: Event-Dispatching Thread VS Stopwatch

Tags: java, swing

I have a java program with a GUI based on Swing. In the main class there are some computations which are grouped in a separate thread. My problem is : I need to start a stopwatch when those computations begin, show the timer WHILE THEY PROCEEDING, stop as they finish. 
If I only needed to count the time left I would start the stopwatch in the separate thread do all computations in the main thread and when they finished stopped the stopwatch thread and display the timer. 
As I know java swing is singlethreaded. So that I can repaint the digiths of the stopwatch in the main swing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've read that `SwingWorker` seems to be what I need.

I'll endorse @Ernest Friedman-Hill's `javax.swing.Timer` suggestion, but this [`SwingWorker`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637725) is worth exploring. It may help you leverage your existing thread code.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest thing to do would be to use a javax.swing.Timer. It's easy to have a Timer send periodic update events to update the GUI, and it's easy to stop or reset the timer as needed.

Comment: THank you for your answer, but I need to stop a timer when all the calculations finished and that is not a periodic action. Is there any way to provide a notification?

Comment: The timer tick itself for your stopwatch **is** a periodic action, and yes the Timer can easily be stopped by simply calling stop() on your Timer instance.

Comment: but my timer works perfectly =) I need a notification from computations to the timer that they all are done. When a timer catches this notification it must stop. The timer's GUI is 3 JLabels: jlbl_min : jlbl_seconds : jlbl_millis. So that I should repaint one or several labels each millisecond the timer is working in event-dispatcher thread...

Comment: I've read about SwingWorker it seems what I need. Am I right?

Comment: It sounds like you could simply have a boolean value that defaults to true. While it is true, keep updating the timer labels. Then when the computations are done, set it to false and the timer will in essence be 'stopped'.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I want to say thank you to everybody.

The problem was solved by usind SwingWorker in such a way: the main swing window I developed as a child of *SwingWorker*. All the computations were in *doInBackground* method. While they were proceeding, a timer (which is in a separate thread) was invoked in SwingUtilities.invokeLater. In the *done* method when all the computations finished the timer was stopped.

Answer (score 0):

The Swing timer will more or less do the job, but it can be somewhat inaccurate. In fact, the inaccuracy can be noticeable. For instance, if you make your timer with the Swing Timer and then watch the numbers as they tick by, you might notice it isn't always exactly a second in between ticks. In other words the resolution of the timer isn't that great.

An alternative to the Swing Timer is `System.nanoTime()`. I always use this. It has much better resolution. It returns the current system time in nano seconds as a long.

Here is a quick example of how you could use this to count by the seconds:

```
long previousTime = 0L;
int seconds = 0;
while(true)
{
    long currTime = System.nanoTime();

    if((currTime - previousTime) / 1000000000L >= 1L)
    {
        previousTime = currTime;
        seconds++;
        System.out.println("Seconds: " seconds)
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, "Timer" is a misnomer. You don't use them to time anything; you use them to give you periodic notifiction. You wake up, you check the time -- possibly using System.nanoTime() -- and react accordingly. In any case, if I was using a Time to update the second hand of a clock, I'd do 250ms wakeups, most of which would just be ignored.

Comment: Thank's for the answer! I wrote a timer myself and it really works  well. The problem is that it is based on Swing and because Swing is singlethreaded I can't provide a notification from calculations (from separate thread) to that timer to stop.

Comment: The while loop was just for proof of concept, if you move the contents of the while loop to the loop in your code where you are updating the GUI interface it should work well for your purposes.